# Ports not Forwarding to Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, port-forwarding

I have set up a simple LAMP and OpenSSH server, which is operating normally. That is, from the intranet. Accessing webpages/ssh is impossible from outside of my network.

I am fairly confident that I have set up my port forwarding properly on my router. I have done it before with Steam, Minecraft, and several other games with great success. My server has access to the internet, I can retrieve packages and ping Google just fine. I have also tested odd ports like 13124 to ensure that it is not my ISP blocking ports.

I've tried setting up iptables (although as far as I know, all ports are open by default):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:13124
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:24113

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I've tried logging packets with tcpdump, but found I was receiving nothing on those ports from external sources. Which leads me back to my router, what could I possibly be doing wrong?

Here is my wireless network info from ifconfig:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:14:a5:8c:1b:26
          inet addr:192.168.1.200  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::214:a5ff:fe8c:1b26/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11658 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5339 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1769099 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:6433857 (6.4 MB)
```

As well as my network interfaces configuration:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# WhiteBox
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
gateway 192.168.1.100
wireless-essid WhiteBox
wireless-key XXXXXXXXXX
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.100
```

And my router port forwards (DLink DIR-615 B2, Firmware V 2.25):
[image: Port forwarding setup on router for HTTP and SSH]

What is causing inbound connections to never reach my server? What can I do to further debug the setup between my server and my router? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally gotten to the bottom of this and the answer is that with the information provided, I did everything right.

The catch was that my network is funky. My router is linked to a modem, as most networks probably are. However, my modem doubles as a router. What had happened was all of the ports were being blocked by my "modem". I forwarded all of the ports on my modem to my actual router, and things are running just fine now. I've also fixed a lot of other problems related to this.

Thanks for trying to help guys, I really appreciate it. And my apologies for asking such an unsolvable question. (Moderators: I'm fairly new to Stack Exchange, so I am not sure if I should delete this question, as it will not help other people, or what. I'm not sure what is the best way to move forward while not harming the community, if that makes sense.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance on a resedential ISP? They tend to block ports like that. You could call them if so, but I don't know if they'd open the ports. You could also switch the stuff to ports outside of the usual web server, etc range, and it might not block.

Comment: I tried ports 13124 and 24113, which are uncommon, with no success.

Comment: @Maxattax Very odd. Just to confirm, you've set up the web server to accept these ports?

Comment: Too as far an extent as I know: router port forwarding; apache2.conf listens on 80, 8080, 13124; 000-default.conf listens on 13124 currently (but I have set to 80 and 8080 as well); iptables are set to open on 80, 8080, 22, 13124, 24113.

Comment: Temporarily turn on logging on the D-Link, send the logs to your server, read `man 5 rsyslog.conf`. Also, are you running `ufw`?